# Cannot call method 'drawImage' of null

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to add a video on the back of a canvas as a background. The problem is that it keeps on giving this error Cannot call method 'drawImage' of null. Please help

```
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    videoContext = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
```

and then i have a function further down the code where the error is happening

```
function render() {

    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
    camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);


    if ( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ) {
videoContext.drawImage( video, 0, 0 );           
    }
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

the videoContext is always staying null

Comment: Is this what you want to do?: http://kesilconsulting.com/web-designer-magazine/html-video-background-tutorial/

Comment: No I have a video I just want to add it on the back of a canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to have a webgl and  2d context from the same canvas.

Comment: so what can i do to add the video as backgroung